# How to iterate over each element in a jagged array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have one 2 dimensional array, so an array of arrays. The arrays of the arrays DONT have the same lengths.
Here an example:

```
double[][] multi = new double[][] { 
  { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }, 
  { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 }, 
  { 1.2, 3.2 },
  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } 
};
```

How can I loop through the columns? (Like: `10 1.1 1.2 1`)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Each row is an array. An array has a `length` attribute.

Comment: Your question is *unclear*. How will it behave on column 3, for example (let's say you want to print the columns)? Should it print `30, 3.3, null, 3`?

Comment: It should skip the value. 30, 3.3, 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this to iterate the whole array **column-wise**:

```
// Get the maximum number of columns among all rows.
int maximumColumns = 0;
for (double[] row : multi) {
    if (row.length > maximumColumns) {
        maximumColumns = row.length;
    }
}

for (int column = 0; column < maximumColumns ; column++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < multi.length; row++) {
        if (column >= multi[row].length) {
            // There is no value for this column.
        } else {
            // Do stuff here with multi[row][column].
        }
    }
}
```

For a specific column **that exists in all rows** do this:

```
int columnToIterate = // Your column.
for (int row = 0; row < multi.length; row++) {
    if (columnToIterate < multi[row].length) {
        // Do stuff here with multi[row][columnToIterate].
    }
}
```

Comment: The first example does what you want. Note that you can use `if (column < multi[row].length)` for `multi[row][column]` only and leave the `else` branch, if you want to ignore non-existent values.

Comment: Note that `multi[row].length` will throw an exception if `multi[row]` is null (and since arrays can be null, this is a possibility).

Answer (score 6):

2D arrays are array of arrays... So one can iterate as:

```
   for (double[] row: multi) {
       for(double value: row) {
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<multi.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<multi[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println("Values at multi["+i+"]["+j+"] is "+multi[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In jagged array, the first index is row index, the second index is the column index (e.g. multi[rowIndex][columnIndex])

```
  for (int row = 0; row < multi.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < multi[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(multi[row][column]);
        }
    }
```