# How to iterate over indices of a matrix?

Tags: java, dl4j, nd4j

In Python when we want to iterate over a matrix with an arbitrary dimension, we can use this line of code:

```
for index in np.ndindex(data.shape[2:]):
```

for example :

```
> for index in np.ndindex(3, 2, 1):
>     print(index) (0, 0, 0) (0, 1, 0) (1, 0, 0) (1, 1, 0) (2, 0, 0) (2, 1, 0)
```

in java, in an easy way, we can do it with a determined number of for loop, but the prerequisite is knowledge about the dimension. But in arbitrary dimensions, the algorithm must be more complicated.

Is there any built-in method in ND4J lib for iterating over indices?

Comment: You think `Java` is an appropriate tag here?

Comment: In java arbituary dimension arrays are called `jagged arrays` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961513/how-to-iterate-over-each-element-in-a-jagged-array   See answer of @SaiNageswar

Comment: Absolutely yes. Java is a right tag. The nd4j is a java library, and in essence my question is how to rewrite a python code in java

Comment: Thank you lovesh. It is not excatly what i look for but it helped

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri he is talking about the nd4j library and the INDArray data structure (similar to the numpy array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nd4j, we have a [NDIndexIterator](https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/blob/master/nd4j/nd4j-backends/nd4j-tests/src/test/java/org/nd4j/linalg/api/iterator/NDIndexIteratorTest.java) that allows you to iterate over the coordinates.

Here is the example:

```
NdIndexIterator shapeIter = new NdIndexIterator(2, 2);
//import org.nd4j.linalg.api.iter.NdIndexIterator;

long[][]  possibleSolutions = new long[][] {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1},};
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    assertArrayEquals(possibleSolutions[i], shapeIter.next());
}
```

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers.. besides, your link does not work.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri mind rescinding your dowvote? I fixed it based on your feedback. That link was working for me earlier but it appears to be cached. Please ease up a bit and allow people to fix it.